# get commandlink value using JS

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandlink

I have a link `commandLink` with value and onclick attributes, When I click on the link it should call a function in JS to get commandLink value. but it returns `undefined` in alert.
How can I get commandLink value ?

```
function callActionMethod(){
    var param1 = $j("#rowlink").val();
    alert(param1);
}

<apex:commandLink reRender="testlabel" 
                  id="rowlink" 
                  onclick="callActionMethod()" 
                  value="{!accounts.id}" />
```

Comment: It may help if you explain why you're trying to do this, there may be smoother solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter directly to the function; there's no need to do this with jQuery (or any JavaScript), at all.

```
<script>
function callActionMethod(param) {
    alert(param);
}
</script>
<apex:commandLink value="{!accounts.id}" onclick="callActionMethod('{!accounts.id}')" />
```

---

Fully functional example:

```
<apex:page controller="myControllerA">
<script>
function callActionMethod(recordId) {
    readCell(recordId);
}
</script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}" reRender="form">
            <apex:param value="" name="recordId" assignTo="{!selectedId}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageMessages/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="account">
            <apex:commandLink value="{!account.name}" onclick="callActionMethod('{!account.id}'); return false;"/><br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but could you help me with this ? I put after alert, another method readCell(param) .. but the value was null. <apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}">
            <apex:param name="parameter1" value="" assignTo="{!test}"/>
      </apex:actionFunction>

Comment: @user3003810 You have to cancel the commandLink's event or all bets are off. Here's an example: `<apex:commandLink value="{!account.name}" onclick="updateRecord('{!account.id}'); return false;" />`. The "return false" causes the link's action to be canceled (which is okay, because updateRecord will call the action method).

Comment: @user3003810 Added a fully functional example (controller not included).

Comment: The controller : 
`public integer test {set; get;}
 public string val {set; get;}
public PageReference readCellMethod(){
        val = 'You have entered : 1 - '+test;
}`

Comment: thank you very much, I used actionSupport instead of actionFunction and everything is fine ! thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this you can use:

```
<apex:commandLink reRender="testlabel" id="rowlink" onclick="callActionMethod()" 
                  value="{!accounts.id}" />

function callActionMethod(){
      var param1 = $j("#rowlink").attr('value');
      alert(param1);
}
```

Comment: still undefined ..

Answer (score 2):

1. Command Link's "value" isn't an actual "value" (i.e. val() won't work, it is not an input element). use `$().html()` instead.
2. You need to address the element as a "managed ID" value (e.g. `{!$Component.rowlink}` instead of `rowlink`). For example, `$("[id='{!$Component.rowlink}']")`.
3. If this ID is further embedded in a repeat, you probably need to use `$("[id$=rowlink]")` to get all row's values.
4. You may want to use a Visualforce HTML5 data pass through if you want to store a custom attribute.